# Segmentation Fault on Linked List Using C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am new to C and try to learn how to implement C on linked list. I am really confused why I can't access myList in the main function? because when I try to `myList->data`, it's segmentation fault. I think there's some error in my addtohead function? 
Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE{
    int data;
    struct NODE *next;
}node;

node * myList;

node * addToHead(node*, int);
void printList();

int main(){
    myList = NULL;
    int input;
    while (scanf("%i",&input) == 1){
           addToHead(myList, input);
           printf("%d \n", myList->data);
       }

    printf("My List:\n");
    printList(myList);
    return 0;
}

node* addToHead(node* head, int newData){
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> data = newData;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL){
        temp -> next = head;
        }
    head = temp;
    return head;
}

void printList(node* head){
    node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You have done nothing with the function's return value. The argument `head` is a *copy* of the one in main. Try `myList = addToHead(myList, input);`.

Comment: `head` into `addToHead` has local scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your addToHead function is supposed to return the `mallocat`ed memory back to caller.

So you should assign the return value to mylist at first:

```
int main(){
    node *myList = NULL;
    int input;
    while (scanf("%i",&input) == 1){
           myList = addToHead(myList, input);
           printf("%d \n", myList->data);
       }

    printf("My List:\n");
    printList(myList);
    return 0;
}
```

Into your `addToHead` function you wrote

```
head = temp;
```

But `head` has local scope and the assigned value is not reflected to the pointer `myList`.

To do so you have to use pointer to pointer.

```
int main(){
    node *myList = NULL;
    int input;
    while (scanf("%i",&input) == 1)
    {
       if (addToHead(&myList, input) == true)
       {
           printf("%d \n", myList->data);
       }
       else
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error addToHead\n");
       }
    }

    return 0;
}

bool addToHead(node** head, int newData){
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
       temp -> data = newData;
       temp -> next = NULL;
       if(head != NULL)
       {
          temp -> next = *head;
       }

       *head = temp;

       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

**Finally** always remember to check the `malloc` return value: it can fail.

Answer (score 0):

You return the new head node from `addToHead`, but you don't do anything with it.  You need to assign this value to `myList` to update it:

```
myList = addToHead(myList, input);
```

Also, you misspelled a variable on the following line:

```
printf("%d \n", myListd->data);
```

It should be:

```
printf("%d \n", myList->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function definition

```
node* addToHead(node* head, int newData){
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> data = newData;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL){
        temp -> next = head;
        }
    head = temp;
    return head;
}
```

The parameter `node* head` is a local variable of the function. Any changes of the parameter will not influence on the original argument. The function parameters will be destroyed after exiting the function.

You can consider the function definition and its call the following way

```
addToHead(myList, input);
//...
node* addToHead(/*node* head, int newData*/){
    node *head = myList;
    int newData = input;

    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp -> data = newData;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL){
        temp -> next = head;
        }
    head = temp;
    return head;
}
```

So the original variable `myList` will not be changed after the function call. You have to assign explicitly the returned value to the variable

```
myList = addToHead(myList, input);
```

Also the function has a drawback. It does not report an error in case when the new node was not allocated.

A better approach to write the function looks the following way

```
int /* _Bool */ addToHead( node **head, int newData )
{
    node *temp = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int /* _Bool */ success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp -> data = newData;
        temp -> next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

In this case the function can be called in a loop the following way

```
while ( scanf( "%i", &input ) == 1 && addToHead( &myList, input ) )
{
    //...
}
```